# The questions about ADR.W instruction

Tags: arm, thumb2

When reversing a ARM firmware using IDA Pro, I find a instruction:

ROM:080461FC 0F F2 24 30         ADR.W      R0, aBt_test_mode ; "BT_TEST_MODE"

...

ROM:08046524    aBt_test_mode       DCB "BT_TEST_MODE",0

...

I know this is a Thumb-2 instruction.
[image]
imm8=0010 0100

Rd=0000

imm3=011

but I don't know how to calculate imm32. (imm32 = ZeroExtend(i:imm3:imm8, 32))
and how to calculate the 08046524?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you have -

`imm8 = 0010 0100`

`imm3 = 011`

but you also have

`i = 0`

then

`imm32 = ZeroExtend(i:imm3:imm8,32) =>`

`imm32 = ZeroExtend(0:011:00100100,32) =>`

`imm32 = ZeroExtend(001100100100,32) =>`

`imm32 = 00000000000000000000001100100100 = 0x00000324`

The ADR instruction description explains that "This instruction adds an immediate value to the PC value to form a PC-relative address, and writes the result to the
destination register."

As you are in Thumb mode, the value of PC is equal to the (4 byte aligned) address of the instruction + 4 bytes. 
In your case the instruction is at address `0x080461FC` so `PC = 0x080461FC + 4 = 0x08046200`

The address calculation is then -

`PC + imm32 = 0x08046200 + 0x00000324 = 0x08046524`

This is what you see in IDA's disassembly.

If you look in the 'Operation' section of the ADR instruction in the ARM architecture reference manual you can see this explained.